# How to report an achievement in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

Basically I'm reporting an achievement inside of Game Center. Here is the code for doing this in Objective-C:

```
(void) reportAchievementIdentifier: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (float) percent
{
    GKAchievement *achievement = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: identifier];
    if (achievement)
    {
         achievement.percentComplete = percent;
         [GKAchievement reportAchievements:@[achievement] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
         {
              if (error != nil)
              {
                  NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
              }
         }];
    }
}
```

Specifically I'm not sure how to complete the Completion Handler.

I tried this but I'm getting an error:

```
class func ReportAchievment(identifier : String, percentComplete : Double)
    {
        var achievement = GKAchievement(identifier: identifier)

        if(achievement != nil)
        {
            achievement.percentComplete = percentComplete;


            GKAchievement.reportAchievements(achievement, withCompletionHandler: { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
                println("Hello, its reported.")
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> GKAchievement Class Reference : http://goo.gl/r9FB0b

`GKAchievement.reportAchievements:` expect an array (not a single object) for the first parameter.

You need to put your `achievement` in an array, or doing simply like so `[achievement]` for the first parameter :

```
GKAchievement.reportAchievements([achievement], ...
```

*I haven't check your completion handler, let us know if you have any issue there too.*